# Import python module from separate directory

Tags: python, import, module, directory

My folder structure is:

```
├── python_ins
    ├── folder1
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── module.py
    │
    └── folder2
        └── main.py
```

`module.py` is empty, and `main.py` looks like:

```
from python_ins.folder1 import module
```

When I run `main.py` from terminal inside `folder2`, it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
     from python_ins.folder1 import module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python_ins'
```

I have the `__init__` file in place, so I don't think I need to append or insert anything to `sys.path`? Why doesn't this work? The absolute path to `python_ins` looks like:

```
/Users/my.name/temp/python_ins/
```

Comment: Is the directory that `python_ins` is in on your Python path? For development that usually means having `/Users/my.name/temp` as your current working directory.

Comment: Also, since `python_ins` is being treated as a package, make sure that you're always invoking your "main" module as a submodule of that package, not as a top-level script. Use `python3 -m python_ins.folder2.main`, not `python3 ./python_ins/folder2/main.py`.